# how to get record count per day in last week (7 days) oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, common-table-expression

hello i am using the following sql query to get **records count per hour in last 24 hours**:

```
WITH date_range
  AS (SELECT TRUNC(sysdate - (rownum/24),'HH24') as the_hour
        FROM dual
      CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 24),
     the_data
  AS (SELECT TRUNC(systemdate, 'HH24')  AS log_date, count(*) AS num_obj
        FROM transactionlog where merchantcode='merc0003'
      GROUP BY TRUNC(systemdate, 'HH24'))   
SELECT TO_CHAR(dr.the_hour,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI AM'), NVL(trans_log.num_obj,0)
FROM date_range dr LEFT OUTER JOIN the_data  trans_log
     ON trans_log.log_date =  dr.the_hour
ORDER BY dr.the_hour DESC ;
```

I am trying to get **record count per day in oracle for last 7 days** .. can some one guide what i may do to get last 7 days by changing above query?

i tried following to get last 7 days, but no gain as yet:

```
WITH date_range
  AS
(SELECT TRUNC(sysdate - (7)) as the_hour
        FROM dual
      CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 7),
     the_data
  AS (SELECT TRUNC(systemdate, 'HH24')  AS log_date, count(*) AS num_obj
        FROM transactionlog where merchantcode='merc0003'
      GROUP BY TRUNC(systemdate, 'HH24'))   
SELECT TO_CHAR(dr.the_hour,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI AM'), NVL(trans_log.num_obj,0)
FROM date_range dr LEFT OUTER JOIN the_data  trans_log
     ON trans_log.log_date =  dr.the_hour
ORDER BY dr.the_hour DESC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is you are not adding days; you are retrieving the same day seven times. Add `level` (or `level - 1`, whichever you want) to the day:

```
SELECT TRUNC(sysdate) - 7 + level AS the_hour
FROM dual
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised your initial CTE even worked. I had not heard of using `CONNECT BY` together with `ROWNUM` (although, having done some Googling, I understand that it works under some conditions. Still, I'm convinced that it's a misuse). To get a date range of the last seven days you'll want something like the following:

```
WITH date_range AS (
    -- If you want to include today's date, add +1 to the date below
    SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE - LEVEL) AS the_date
      FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7
)
```

Putting this together with your existing query:

```
WITH date_range AS (
    SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE - LEVEL) AS the_date
      FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7
), the_data AS (
    -- You still had 'HH24' here in the call to TRUNC()!
    SELECT TRUNC(systemdate) AS log_date, count(*) AS num_obj
      FROM transactionlog
     WHERE merchantcode = 'merc0003'
     GROUP BY TRUNC(systemdate)
)
SELECT dr.the_date, COALESCE(trans_log.num_obj, 0)
  FROM date_range dr LEFT JOIN the_data trans_log
    ON dr.the_date = trans_log.log_date
 ORDER BY dr.the_date DESC;
```

Incidentally, you can just use aliases for your CTEs; you don't need to give them full names only to alias them again.